# change link in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want change link video old server to new server From sql

old link

http://content.xxxx.com/api

i want change to

http://163.172.716.323/api/

From sql

Comment: Fire an update query......

Comment: Could you please provide some detail. your question is not clear.

Comment: https://snag.gy/GB6Vjq.jpg

show print screen old link in link

i want change link to

http://163.172.716.323/api/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UPDATE` query

```
update your_table set column_to_update='http://163.172.716.323/api/'
where column_to_update LIKE '%content.xxxx.com%'
```

If column contains same value, then no need to add `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

https://snag.gy/GB6Vjq.jpg

show print screen 
old link in link

i want change link to

http://163.172.716.323/api/

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename SET file_server_path = CONCAT('http://163.172.716.323/api/',
    SUBSTRING(file_server_path, 38)) WHERE 
    file_server_path LIKE 'http://content.xXxXxXx.com/api/files/%'
```

Short explanation:

- `WHERE field_name LIKE 'old_url%'` is used to only select rows that start with the url we want to replace, the `%` acts as a wildcard
- `SUBSTRING(field_name, start_index)` is used to get the field contents after the URL, start_index points to the position after the URL (same as `CHAR_LENGTH('old_url')` + 1)
- `CONCAT(new_url, old_url_substring)` is used to create a single string that is composed of the new URL followed by the substring we extracted